# Array to string conversion notice when using PHP to email dynamic data from html form.

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have built an HTML form that has buttons to add rows for multiple inputs. I want to email all the rows with the input data no matter how many rows are added. So far I get the email but its only 1 row of data and all the input fields are saying "Array" and I receive the notice of "Array to string conversion on line 34" & "Array to string conversion on line 41"

Is this even possible?

HTML Form Code:

```
                <form action="Email.php" method="POST">
        <table id="2HL" name="Pass">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:120%">Date</font></td>
                <td><input type="datetime" name="Date"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:120%">Team Lead</font></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Team_Lead"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font style="color: #00008b; font-size:120%">End of Shift Information:</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table id="Cellinfo">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td Type="text" name="Cell"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">CELL</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Goal"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">GOAL</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Comp"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">COMP</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="LTD"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">LTD</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="WET_SKU"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">WET SKU</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="clone">
                        <td><input type="text" name="Cell[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Goal[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Comp[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="LTD[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="WET_SKU[]"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value="ADD ROW" /><br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font style="color: #00008b; font-size:120%">Impediment Notes:</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table id="impediment">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td Type="text" name="Cell0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">CELL</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="SKU0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">SKU</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Part0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">PART #</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Impediment0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">IMPEDIMENT TYPE</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="QTYadj0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">QTY ADJUSTED</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Partloc0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">PART LOCATION</font></td>
                        <td Type="text" name="Comments0"><font style="color: #b22222; font-size:100%">TEAM LEAD COMMENTS</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="clone1">
                        <td><input type="text" name="Cella[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="SKU[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Part[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Impediment[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="QTYadj[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Partloc[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Comments[]" size="75"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="button" onclick="cloneimpediment()" value="ADD ROW" /><br>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Email Form">
        </P>
    </form>
```

Java Code to Add Rows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function cloneRow()
    {
        var row = document.getElementById("clone"); // find row to copy
        var table = document.getElementById("Cellinfo"); // find table to append to
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
        clone.id = "clone"; // change id or other attributes/contents
        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }
function cloneimpediment()
    {
        var row = document.getElementById("clone1"); // find row to copy
        var table = document.getElementById("impediment"); // find table to append to
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
        clone.id = "clone1"; // change id or other attributes/contents
        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }

</script>
```

PHP Code Here:

```
<?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 

$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Team_Lead = $_POST['Team_Lead'];
$Cell = $_POST['Cell'];
$Goal = $_POST['Goal'];
$Comp = $_POST['Comp'];
$LTD = $_POST['LTD'];
$WET_SKU = $_POST['WET_SKU'];
$Cella = $_POST['Cella'];
$SKU = $_POST['SKU'];
$Part = $_POST['Part'];
$Impediment = $_POST['Impediment'];
$QTYadj = $_POST['QTYadj'];
$Partloc = $_POST['Partloc'];
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
}
$email_from = 'TestTeamLead@moen.com';
$email_subject = "Pass Down Test";
$email_body = "<html><body>";
$email_body .= '<table border="1">';
$email_body .= "<tr><td>Date</td><td>$Date</td></tr>";
$email_body .= "<tr><td>Team Lead</td><td>$Team_Lead</td></tr>";
$email_body .= "</table>";
$email_body .= "<br>";
$email_body .= "END OF SHIFT INFORMATION:";
$email_body .= "<br>";
$email_body .= '<table border="1">';
$email_body .= '<tr><td>Cell</td><td>Goal</td><td>Comp</td><td>LTD</td><td>WET SKU</td></tr>';
$email_body .= "<tr><td>$Cell</td><td>$Goal</td><td>$Comp</td><td>$LTD</td><td>$WET_SKU</td></tr>";
$email_body .= "</table>";
$email_body .= "<br>";
$email_body .= "IMPEDIMENT NOTES:";
$email_body .= "<br>";
$email_body .= '<table border="1">';
$email_body .= '<tr><td>Cell</td><td>SKU</td><td>PART #</td><td>ImpedimentType</td><td>QTY Adjusted</td><td>Part Location</td><td>TEAM LEAD Comments</td></tr>';
$email_body .= "<tr><td>$Cella</td><td>$SKU</td><td>$Part</td><td>$Impediment</td><td>$QTYadj</td><td>$Partloc</td><td>$Comments</td></tr>";
$email_body .= "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess here `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)` you want to iterate through all of the HTML table rows. But the thing is that you have on server exactly what you've specified on client.
Try `print_r($_POST)`, so you'll have an idea of the data that comes to server. You should iterate through a random key of yours or rewrite the client code to get the php script in accordance.

Comment: You should try using foreach as mentioned by crrad

Answer (score 0):

Code on line 31 and 41 are arrays, you should iterate in for loop to show them in html, that is why you get array notice.why are your input field name atribute set as array []?

Comment: Okay so I removed the array [] mark up from my field name attributes and I got the data from the first row of the form.

Comment: How do I now get the rest of the rows that may be added by using the buttons?